# Inequality (Decay of Green function)

Tags: inequality, fourier-transform, greens-function

Let $d\ge 3$ be an integer and $m,r>0$. Then how would one show that
$$
\int_m^\infty (s^2-m^2)^{(d-3)/2}e^{-sr}ds \le \frac{C}{r^{(d-1)/2}} e^{-mr}
$$
for somce constant $C$ which may depend on $m$ but not $r$.

*Background.* The LHS is basically the Fourier transform $G(x)$ of $1/(k^2+m^2)$ at $x$ where $|x|=r$ (you can check this by taking $d=3$). It is known that $G(x)$ is bounded by the RHS (or at least, I have seen papers mentioning this), but how would one prove the aforementioned inequality.

Comment: Does $C$ depend on $m$ and $d$,but not $r$?

Answer (score 1):

To make the story short, using quite obvious changes of variables, the integral is
$$I=\frac{2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \left(\frac{m}{r}\right)^{\frac{d-2}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right)\,K_{\frac{d-2}{2}}(m r)$$ At least, when $m$ is large,we have
$$I=\frac{(2 m)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right) e^{-mr}}{r^{\frac {d-1 } 2}}\Bigg[1+\frac{(d-1)(d-3)}{8 m r}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) \Bigg]$$ If we neglect the high order terms, then you would like to show that
$$\frac{(2 m)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right) e^{-mr}}{r^{\frac {d-1 } 2}} < \frac C {r^{\frac {d-1 } 2}} e^{-mr}$$ that is to say
$$(2 m)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right) < C$$

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Bessel functions, but if your are assuming that $K_\alpha (x) = \int_0^\infty \cosh(\alpha t) e^{-x \cosh{t}}dt$ (as state in Wikipedia), could you elaborate on what kind of change of variables to use? I'm assuming you're setting $s= m \cosh{t}$, but that seems a little different than the necessary integral.form.